# D3.js Barchart, split text

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js

I have D3.js barchart and I want to show numbers from arrays on it. Each bar has its own array with numbers, say, `[12, 34, 65]`. I am able to show just arrays as text at the top of each bar, but I want to split each array and show each number top to bottom, so for `[12, 34, 65]` bar it would be `12` at the bottom, then `34` in the middle and `65` at the top. How to do this? So far I have such code, which just shows me arrays at the top of each bar:

```
        g.selectAll("text")
           .data(dataset)
           .enter()
           .append("text")
           .text(function(d) {
                return d;
           })
           .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
           .attr("font-size", "11px")
           .attr("fill", "white")
           .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
           .attr("x", function(d, i) {
                return ...;
           })          
           .attr("y", function(d) {
                return ...;
           });
```

Where `dataset` is an array of arrays. `d` would then correspond to `[12, 34, 65]`. I need a way of splitting it into individual numbers and specifying `y` for each number. At the same time `x` should stay the same for each bar, obviously. It is also desirable to segment each bar into parts that correspond to each number by either drawing lines b/w numbers or better by changing colors of each segment that corresponds to a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve your problem, you need to handle [nested data with d3](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/nest/), i.e., you need to first create a group for each stacked bar:

```
var stacks = root.selectAll("g.stack")
.data(dataset)
.enter()
.append("g").attr("class","stack")
```

And then for each stack create a new selection with the nested arrays as data by using a new `data` function that extracts the nested arrays from the parent data.

```
var bars = stacks.selectAll("g.bar")
.data(function(d, i) { return d; })
.enter().append(...)
```

For each bar in the stack you can then use a different color, e.g., using `d3.scale.category10`.

Here is complete example:

```js
var root = d3.selectAll("svg>g#root")
var dataset = [[10,20,50],[70,40,10],[20,40,10]]
var color = d3.scale.category10()

dataset.forEach( function(d) {
    d.sort( function(a,b)  { return b-a; } )
})

var stacks = root.selectAll("g.stack")
.data(dataset)
.enter()
.append("g").attr("class","stack")
.attr("transform", function(d,i) {
    return "translate(0,"+ (i * 30) +")"
})

var bars = stacks.selectAll("g.bar")
.data(function(d, i) { return d; })
.enter()
.append("g").attr("class","bar")

var barWidth = function(d,i) { return d * 2 }
var barColor = function(d,i) { return color(i) }

bars.append("rect")
.attr("height", "20")
.attr("x",      "0")
.attr("y",      "0")
.attr("width",  barWidth )
.style("fill",  barColor )

bars.append("text")
.text( function(d) { return d } )
.attr("x", barWidth )
.attr("y", 9)
.attr("transform", "translate(-10,0)" )
```

```css
svg { border: solid 1px gray }

svg text {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size:   11px;
    fill:        white;
    text-anchor: middle;
}

svg rect {
    fill:   gray;
    stroke: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg width=200 height=100 id="container" 
     style="border: solid 1px gray">
    <g id="root" transform="translate(10,10)"></g>
</svg>
```

Note that, for brevity, the example does not use any `d3.scale` to convert from data space to geometry space. Please refer to the [d3 wiki](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Scales) for more details.

The example currently assumes that the values in the arrays are absolute values, i.e., with all bars starting at `x="0"`. If you need real stacking of relative values, I suggest to first precompute a corresponding value for `x`, for each bar, by summing up the previous values of the sorted, nested arrays:

```
var sum = function(a,b) { return a+b }
var derivedData = dataset.map( function(d,i) {
    d.sort( function(a,b)  { return b-a; } )
    return d.map( function(v,i) {
        // `value` determines the width or height of a bar
        // `sum`   determines the position of the bar
        return { value: v, sum: d.slice(0,i+1).reduce(sum) }
    })
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok I have a dataset where i have labels in the form of an array as you said that *Each bar has its own array with numbers, say, `[12, 34, 65]`*

```
{
    "letter": "B",
        "frequency": 0.03492,
    label: [10, 20, 30]//this is the array which will be displayed on bar's top middle bottom
}
```

To append the label on the bar do like this

```
var rects = svg.selectAll(".bar")
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("g");
//make the bars
rects.append("rect")
    .attr("class", "bar")
    .attr("x", function (d) {
    return x(d.letter);
})
    .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
    .attr("y", function (d) {
    return y(d.frequency);
})
    .attr("height", function (d) {
    return height - y(d.frequency);
});
//text @ the top
rects.append("text")
    .attr("x", function (d) {
    return x(d.letter) + x.rangeBand() / 2;
})
    .attr("y", function (d) {
    return y(d.frequency) + 10;
}).attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
    .attr("font-size", "11px")
    .attr("fill", "white")
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .text(function (d) {
    return d.label[0];
});
//text @ the middle
rects.append("text")
    .attr("x", function (d) {
    return x(d.letter) + x.rangeBand() / 2;
})
    .attr("y", function (d) {
    return (height + y(d.frequency))/2;
}).attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
    .attr("font-size", "11px")
    .attr("fill", "white")
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .text(function (d) {
    return d.label[1];
});
//text @ the bottom
rects.append("text")
    .attr("x", function (d) {
    return x(d.letter) + x.rangeBand() / 2;
})
    .attr("y", function (d) {
    return height - 10;
}).attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
    .attr("font-size", "11px")
    .attr("fill", "white")
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .text(function (d) {
    return d.label[2];
});
```

Working code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/2jf4rhqd/)

Hope this helps!